# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxx After using pyarmor pack

Tags: python, pyarmor

I am using

> pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile" main.py

After Running the Compiled .py file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<dist \obf\ Builder19948 .py>", line 3, in <module>
File "<frozen Builder19948> ", line 7, in <module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard"
[12560] Failed to execute script *Builder19948 due to unhandled exception!
```

I have imported keyboard module in my code, so how can I Fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: If the module is called `keyboard`, why is the error message complaining about `keyboand` in line 7?

Comment: because keyboard gets imported on the 7th line

Comment: Look at the spelling.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry it is because of the image-to-text tool I use. its good now

Comment: Then it's probably a dynamic import that `pyarmor`'s static analysis didn’t detect. You may have to specify it explicitly using `--hidden-import`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile" main.py how do I add it to this line? when i try this:  pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile" -e "--hidden-import=keyboard"main.py it gives me a error.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Don't use comments for this. Please [edit] your question to show the modified command line and the message you get. Without knowing what the message says it's impossible to say what might be wrong.